# Confused with fft Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft

I am little bit confused with fft. That would be good if anyone can help me. first, I want to convert fft output in time domain. Where `t = f/k` and `K = BW/Tm` (`BW` = bandwidth & `Tm` = transmit time). After that again i need to take fft and ouput should be box (rectangular function) which is having width of BW(40e9).

```
f1 = 1e6;  % first cutoff frequency

f2 = 4e6;  % second cutoff frequency

BW = 40e9; % bandwidth

Tm = 0.2e-3; % transmit time

fs = 1e7;   % sampling frequency

c = 3e8;    % speed of light

w1 = f1/ (fs/2); % normalizing first cutoff frequency 

w2 = f2/ (fs/2): % normalizing second cutoff frequency

[b,a] = butter(2, [w1,w2], 'bandpass');

load('fb2040');

x = fb2040(3,:);

y_filt = filter(b,a,x); % filtering

nfft = length(y_filt);

res = fft(y_filt, nfft)/ nfft;

f = fs/2 * linspace(0,1,nfft/2+1);

res = res(1:nfft/2+1);

figure, plot(f,abs(res));

xlabel('frequency in MHz'); 

ylabel('amp');

return
```

Comment: This question is quite confusing, to inverse fft, use ifft as specified here: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html?refresh=true. I am not sure what you mean by the second question; do you mean to transform the ifft result back in to fft with a higher bandwidth?

Comment: Hi Game of throws, Thanks for your quick reply. I want to get the amplitude of my signal. I have a output of radar mixer which i have band-passed, took fft so the output is a sinc function. Now in order to get amplitude of my signal, i need to convert first fft output in time domain and than again need to take fft. Since I have converted my first fft output in time domain and the output is sinc function, the second fft will give the ouput as a rectangular function or box.